# How to add rows to a Grid View having columns in c# 2.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am pretty much sure that this question have been asked and answered several times before. But I am asking it again for an alternate answer. Here is my GridView

```
<asp:GridView ID="dgvGeneralBillList" runat="server" style="font-size:11px;margin:10px auto auto 30px;width:500px;" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dgvGeneralBillList_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="BillID" HeaderText="Bill ID" Visible="False" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="SerialNo" HeaderText="Bill No" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="BilledWeekNo" HeaderText="Billed Week" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="BilledWeekDate" HeaderText="Billed Date" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Amount" HeaderText="Amount" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="BillStatus" HeaderText="Bill Status" />
                <asp:CommandField SelectText="Print" ShowSelectButton="True" />
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

Now I want to add rows to this gridview in runtime. In other articles, they suggest to define a `DataTable`, then `ADD my desired COLUMNS` to that table, then `ADD rows in that TABLE` and finally `BIND the table to the GridView`. Yes, This solves the problem and I can also do that. But what I want to do is, as I already have columns added into my gridview, I just want to add rows in it. **and NOT Define a DataTable and then Bind it to GridView stuff**. I tried below,

```
oOutputBill = (clsBill[])oOutput;
            if (oOutputBill.Length > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < oOutputBill.Length; i++)
                {
                    GridViewRow oRow = new GridViewRow();
                    oRow.Cells[0].Text = Convert.ToString(oOutputBill[i].BillID);
                    oRow.Cells[1].Text = Convert.ToString(oOutputBill[i].SerialNo);
                    oRow.Cells[2].Text = Convert.ToString(oOutputBill[i].BilledWeekNo);
                    oRow.Cells[3].Text = Convert.ToString(oOutputBill[i].BilledWeekDate);
                    oRow.Cells[4].Text = Convert.ToString(oOutputBill[i].Amount);
                    oRow.Cells[5].Text = Convert.ToString(oOutputBill[i].BillStatus);
                }
            }
```

and as expected, it gives the error "No Overload of Method GridViewRow takes 0 arguments". How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I am using now as solution.
My GridView is-

```
<asp:GridView ID="dgvGeneralBillList" runat="server" style="font-size:11px;margin:10px auto auto 30px;width:auto;" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dgvGeneralBillList_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="BillID" HeaderText="Bill ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="SerialNo" HeaderText="Bill No" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="BilledWeekNo" HeaderText="Billed Week" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="BilledWeekDate" HeaderText="Billed Date" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Amount" HeaderText="Amount" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="BillStatus" HeaderText="Bill Status" />
                <asp:CommandField SelectText="Print" ShowSelectButton="True" />
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

And the way of adding row is-

```
oOutputBill = (clsBill[])oOutput;
            if (oOutputBill.Length > 0)
            {
                dgvGeneralBillList.DataSource = oOutputBill;
                dgvGeneralBillList.DataBind();
                dgvGeneralBillList.Visible = true;
            }
```

This answer is similar to define a table, add columns to table, add rows to table and finally bind the table to gridview but with less code. in this way, only columns defined in the gridview are bound with the data source. Please note that, if you want to do something similar to **OnSelectedIndexChanged** and try to get any data from the gridview, the **DataColumn** ***HAVE TO*** be **DEFINED** and **VISIBLE** in the gridview. But if anyone can provide me the sample code as my question, it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://blog.falafel.com/blogs/mikedugan/07-04-12/Dynamically_add_rows_to_a_GridView.aspx) link may be helpful.

But I recommend to bind GridView by DataSource. 
Just save your data into session and instead of manually adding rows into GridView, add new row into saved data and rebind your grid.

Example:

```
// If you have List of clsBill.
List<clsBill> oOutputBill = 'Filled from DB...';

// Save Data into session
Session["oOutputBill"] = oOutputBill;

// Bind your GridView
dgvGeneralBillList.DataSource = Session["oOutputBill"];
dgvGeneralBillList.DataBind();

...

// Get saved data and insert new row
List<clsBill> oOutputBill = Session["oOutputBill"] as List<clsBill>;

if(oOutputBill != null)
{
    oOutputBill.Add(new clsBill() { /* Fill class properties */ } );

    // Rebind grid
    dgvGeneralBillList.DataSource = Session["oOutputBill"];
    dgvGeneralBillList.DataBind();
}
```